# dom4j - I want to eliminate blank lines after processing instructions

Tags: java, xml, dom4j

In development of java application, using dom4j library, xml output is done.
I want to add an element of processing instruction after xml declaration, and then write out a normal element.

#### The problem

I want to eliminate the insertion of blank lines after elements of processing instructions.

```java
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        OutputFormat format = new OutputFormat("  ", true, "UTF-8");

        XMLWriter writer = null;
        try {
            Document newDoc = DocumentHelper.createDocument();

            Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            // Add attributes of processing instruction to map
            map.put("type", "text/xsl");
            map.put("href", "../../test/sample.xsl");

            // Generate processing instruction and add to dom
            ProcessingInstruction pi = DocumentHelper.createProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", map);
            List<Node> headerList = newDoc.content();
            headerList.add(0, pi);

            // Add regular element to dom
            Element person= newDoc.addElement("person");
            person.addElement("name");

            // xml export
            fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\demo\\demo.xml");
            writer = new XMLWriter(fos, format);
            writer.write(newDoc);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

demo.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="../../test/sample.xsl"?>
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　//I want to delete this blank line
<person>
  <name/>
</person>
```

#### Try

Even if setNewLineAfterDeclaration of OutputFormat is set to false, it will be as follows if the blank line after xml declaration is deleted.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="../../test/sample.xsl"?>
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　//I want to delete this blank line
<person>
  <name/>
</person>
```

In addition, if setNewLineAfterDeclaration of OutputFormat is false and there is no instruction processing, there was no blank line.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<person>
  <name/>
</person>
```

Can not delete blank lines after processing instruction?
Thank you for your consideration. . .

#### Supplementary information

dom4j  version: 2.1.1